I want to create a form for wordpress plugin using php and HTML forms



ID
post_id
name
class
grades




1
23341
my name
9
{"math":"ninety-one","english":"forty","other":"number"}


2
45434
your name
10
{"math":"ninety-one","english":"forty","other":"number"}



know I have a in total 4 class=[9,10,11,12]
and I create form with input field name, and subject=[math,english,sci,computer]
using foreach loop subject field are created
hence name and subject input field are created
Then I wrap that code in foreach loop for class
i know that does not make sense but this is intensional
reason(for a student each student is in 12th for which each have 9-12 grades for them)
now I want achieve is that to save that data in database using HTML forms
When I tried single entry is working fine
I dont know how to do it for class[]
I want create four rows for each student with different class but same name and different grades
and this should updatable
Here is the processing code
$class = [9,10,11,12]
$name = ["first_name","middle_name","last_name"]
$grades = ["math","english","sci","computer"]

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    global $wpdb, $class_table, $class, $name, $grades;

    $classes = isset($_POST['class']) ? $_POST['class'] : [];
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $grades = [];

    // Check if $class is set and is an array
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // foreach ($classes as $class) {
    if (isset($names) && is_array($names)) {
      foreach ($names as $name) {
        if (!empty($_POST[$name])) {
          $links[$name] = $_POST[$name];
        }
      }
    }
    $existing_entry = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $class_table WHERE post_id = %d AND class = %s AND name = %s", $post_id, $class, $name));
    if ($existing_entry) {
      $existing_grades = json_decode($existing_entry->class, true);
      $merged_grades = array_merge($merged_grades, $grades);
      $merged_grades = array_filter($merged_grades); // Remove empty entries
      $merged_grades = json_encode($merged_grades);
      $update_data = [
        'class' => $class,
        'name' => $name,
        'grades' => $merged_grades,
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
      ];
      $format = [
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d'
      ];
      $where = ['post_id' => $post_id];
      $wpdb->update($movie_table, $update_data, $where, $format);
    } else {
      $insert_data = [
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'name' => $name,
        'name' => $class,
        'grades' => json_encode($grades),
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
      ];
      $format = [
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d'
      ];
      $wpdb->insert($movie_table, $insert_data, $format);
    }
  }

